# how to send sms in a non-activity class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

i have a service class, and a util class.
in util class,i send a sms to a phone. but in util class ,there are many functions use params such as context,but the util extends nothing,just a simple class. how to do it ?

Comment: Use a reference of the Activity Context to send Sms from Non activity class

Answer (score 2):

Just like this. set all pendingIntent null.

```
public static boolean smsSender(String to, String msg) {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    try {

            List<String> contents = smsManager.divideMessage(msg);
            for (String content : contents){
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(to, null, content, null, null);
            }

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 public class ABCD extends Service{

           Util util = new Util(this);

    }



public class Util{
              private Context context = null;
              public Util(Context context){
                    this.context = context;
              }
  }
```

Comment: Note that storing the `Context` object like that is a BAD idea. You'll keep a reference to it and it won't be garbage collected once it's destroyed (unless ABCD is garbage collected as well). Instead, use the `Context` immediately to get access to the SMS service.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you will have to pass the context as an argument when creating whatever object you are making with the util class.

So, I assume in your service class, you are making a Util class which sends the sms... I'll just make up some code that may fit what you are doing...

Within your service class, do this.

```
Util util = new Util(this)
```

Doing that will create a Util object which has the context of the service, just make sure the Util class has a proper constructor to *retain* the context (for later use). Do this using this in your Util class

```
public class Util {

    private Context c                //storage for the Context

    public Util (Context context){   //constructor for Util
        this.c = context;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.