# send textmessage from non activity class in android

Tags: android, android-activity, sms

I want to send sms from a non activity class. I have passed Activity and context reference to my non activity class like below:

```
public AlertHelper(Context cont, Activity act) {
        context = cont;
        activity = act;
    }
```

Now I am trying to send an sms from this AlertHelper(non activity class) by using below code:

```
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
String message = "my sms";
String doctor = "9999999999";
smsMgr.sendTextMessage(doctor, null, message, null,null);
```

but textmessage is not being send. I have moved above 4 line to an Activity class and it is working fine.

so I want to ask how can i get text messaging done in non avtivity class. Please help me!!!
I have referenced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116488/how-to-send-sms-in-a-non-activity-class).

Comment: did you add permission to your manifest to send SMS?

Comment: Does your logcat show any exceptions?

Comment: I have already added permission to manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

According android documentation do you need request permission to this.

`SEND_SMS`  Allows an application to send SMS messages.'

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

In additional

`READ_SMS`  Allows an application to read SMS messages.

Comment: This appears to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Tanis.7x i can not add comments because : "add comment (requires 50 reputation)". So what is the solution when I am trying help anyone here? Thanks

Comment: actually what you have mentioned is absolutely correct , but the site needs quality answers , so you are getting down votes, so what you need to do is edit your answer @betorcs

Comment: Instead of asking a question, you could phrase your question as a possible answer (e.g. "Add the SEND_SMS permission to your manifest"). A good answer also includes sample code and/or an explanation as appropriate. In this case, the correct `<uses-permission>` tag from the manifest would make this a much more high quality answer.

Comment: I have already added permission to manifest file. I am sure there would be something related to context or Activity which i am missing to perform.

Comment: I did a code like yours and worked. Your code looks be right. I assume can be a carrier problem. I suggest you try another device or other carrier.

Comment: Code available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6e1tdmz2yzxk5d6/MyApplicationProject.zip

Answer (score 0):

Add `SEND_SMS` permission in your Manifest and `RECEIVE_SMS` if you would also like to read messages.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: This link tells you how to send SMS within your Android application: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sending-sms-from-android-application/

Comment: thanks for link. I know how to send sms but I want to know how to send sms from non activity class.